# Setting up Azure AD Connect

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to install the preview of Azure AD Connect:

https://connect.microsoft.com/site1164/program8612

During the setup, you can configure the sign-in method for users, synchronization or a federation with ADFS. I want to use ADFS, and I want the setup to configure a new ADFS farm. The setup wants a SSL certificate, so I've made a self-signed certificate and exported it as a .PFX file. However, the setup won't accept the certificate, it states "The certificate is invalid or corrupted. Please try another certificate"

I selected another certificate which I've used for a website, and I get the same result. The certificate chain is OK, I've tried to install the certificate, but no matter what, the setup keeps rejecting the certificate. I can't find any further info in the eventlog or setup log file, and since the Azure AD connect software is quite new and still in preview, there's not much info on the web regarding the installation.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: I think stackoverflow is not the right site to ask this kind of question. Or is it?

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory for AD FS to use a third-party signed certificate. If you don't want to pay for a certificate, you can use one from [wosign](https://www.wosign.com) which is free and publicly trusted (as an intermediate certification authority from VeriSign or similar I think).